# How to make Autoresize property work in Xcode 4.3?

Tags: iphone, xcode, cocoa, uilabel

I recently updated to Xcode 4.3 and it disabled my UILabels' autoshrink property. I rechecked the boxes in IB and rebuilt the project but it is still cutting off the text. Any suggestions? Is this a known bug? Is there a way to fix this programatically.

Comment: Have you tried setting the `UILabel`'s `autoresizingMask` programatically?

Comment: autoresizingMask didn't work.

Comment: adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth is selected in XIB but when the app run it is ignored. It's Xcode 4.3 which causes this problem. So buggy.

Comment: Agreed, it's ultra buggy. IB won't stay consistent... If I check the box it unchecked it and vice versa...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I'm seeing the same thing. You can work around it programmatically (I do it in viewDidLoad):

```
myLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
```

Comment: That did the trick!! Although I used `[myLabel setAdjustsFontSizeToFitWidth:YES];` because I think Apple wants us to "set" properties like such.

Comment: I had the same problem and filed a radar before (http://openradar.appspot.com/10984259). This problem seems to have been fixed in XCode 4.3.1.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. Here's the fix, I added it to a utility method, since I have over 100 xibs in my project, and a bunch of them needed fixing. Works great.

Add this to Utility.m:

```
// UIView+viewRecursion.h
@interface UIView (viewRecursion)
- (NSMutableArray*) allSubViews;
@end
// UIView+viewRecursion.m
@implementation UIView (viewRecursion)
- (NSMutableArray*)allSubViews
{
    NSMutableArray *arr=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [arr addObject:self];
    for (UIView *subview in self.subviews)
    {
        [arr addObjectsFromArray:(NSArray*)[subview allSubViews]];
    }
    return arr;
}
@end
```

And this:

```
  +(void)fixLabels:(UIView *)theView{

    for(UIView *v in [theView allSubViews])
    {
        if([v isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]])
        {
            if( !((UILabel*)v).adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth ){
                ((UILabel*)v).adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth=YES;
                //  NSLog(@"fixed %@", theView);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And then call fixLabels from viewDidLoad for any view that has UILabels that are not auto shrinking:

```
[Utility fixLabels:self.view];
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the exact opposite problem!  I updated to Xcode 4.3, and now it auto shrinks the text in my tableview cells when I want them to truncate them with the ellipses.  I went through the storyboard and modified all of the options that might have to do with that, but it refuses to do what I want.  So frustrating.

Edited...

Try and re-create what Xcode was doing to me since it's the reverse of what's happening to you.  Highlight the prototype cell you have for your tableview in the storyboard and click on the "Title" and "Subtitle" words.  You can find the AutoShrinking property within the attributes inspector, and I suppose you can fix your issue by unchecking this box and rebuilding your app.  Very strange how the Xcode upgrade would cause this.  It also caused my app to behave a bit strangely (i.e. crashing unexpectedly while running in the simulator), but a few clean and rebuilds solved this.  Hopefully you are able to fix this, since I know it was just as frustrating for me!

Comment: Ooops, I guess I solved my own problem.  I had to actually turn Autoshrinking ON in Xcode and set the minimum size to be my text size.  That's friggin goofy.

Comment: Ugh, the bugginess that is Xcode 4.3 isn't resolving itself for me. Every time I build it unselects the autoresize feature and if I hard-code it it ignores it... glad your's is working though!

Answer (score 0):

It just did the same thing to me.  All the autoshrink are turned off.  Putting back a font size and turning auto shrink on didn't actually work.

I had to fix it programmatically as JLundell suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Xcode 4.3 doesn't respecting the Interface Builder Settings for adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth property.

You can fix it by setting the property value programmatically as JLundell suggested.

```
myLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
```

It has been fixed up in 4.3.1